# Computer runs,but won't display anything on screen, changed power supply and graphics card

Tags: boot, display, graphics-card, power-supply, desktop-computer

This computer has not been booting properly recently and I can't figure it out. It has Ubuntu but has worked fine for years. It is a older computer, and nothing has ever been changed except hard drives until now.

The computer started randomly shutting down sometimes or 'suspend', the power button light would blink like it's suspended but you would have to push it and it would go off and then push again to turn back on. It would not respond to anything else except the power button in that state.
Assumed it was overheating from the summer heat and dust build-up, it was cleaned but continued to shut itself off, it would also seem to run better with the side panel popped off at the time.

Then the computer started to boot with a line of text [blurry text from the monitor when it booted before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9YpF.jpg)

This is the only picture I have, it booted once with that text but would boot regularly with just the bottom line of the text on the screen in the photo that says the clean files and blocks thing.

Now the computer turns on, fans run, lights, and sounds like it wants to boot but just a black screen. The monitor does not respond and it has worked fine with this computer for a long time. The graphics card and power supply have been changed to a new power supply and an older unused graphics card. It booted about three times only after changing the graphics card, with a longer boot time than usual, and now it just runs on a black screen and won't boot again.

Any help would be appreciated I can't tell what's wrong with it.

**EDIT:**

It has been awhile but this computer is still giving me issues, I had alot come up and just getting it running was priority at the time. When I unplugged the mouse and keyboard it worked? It came up with a screen that said:

```
AMD FX (tm) 4300 quad core processor     , speed: 200x19=3800 M( the picture i took cuts off here so I can't see the rest of this line)

DRAM Frequency for DDR3 1333 MHz( Unganged mode, 64-bit) DRAM Size is 8192 MB

USB Devices total: 0 KBS ,0 MICE, 0 MASS , 0 HUBS

Detected ATA/ATAPI Devices SATA Port3: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM 6H24NSCO SATA Port5: WDC WD10EZEX-00MFCAO

All settings were reset to default values. press F1 to run setup  press F2 to continue,
```

plugged the keyboard in and hit F2 and it worked for awhile.
It would boot like this fine and I didn't know what was wrong but everything was working and I didn't have alot of time to sit down and look at it so I left it to boot by unplugging the keyboard, turn it on, plug it in and hit F2.
If I left the keyboard in it didn't seem like it would work and  go to a black screen instead but maybe something else was happening there and just happened to boot ok when I unplugged it. Now it has not booted at all the last five times, it would stay on the blank black screen, like the monitor doesn't even turn on, the fans spin, computer lights up, makes sound and then nothing.
I tried it today and it went to the screen that says F1 setup or F2 continue, I hit F1 this time to see if something has changed and I didn't see anything wrong so I clicked discard changes(none) and exited the BIOs screen.
It rebooted to the F1 or F2 screen so I pressed F2 to continue and it started to boot a little slower then normal, went to a purple screen with the mouse cursor on it, I can move the mouse but it does not give me the desktop.

It is currently ubuntu 20.04 and has been for awhile, it usually flashes this purple with the cursor before the desktop appears when it boots but only for a second, It's stuck on purple it seems.
I'm really not sure what's wrong with this thing, I'm not having good luck with anything lately so I didn't want to mess things up worse when it seemed to be working ok. It also apparently isn't backed up fully so hopefully the hard drive is okay, It didn't seem like it was the problem but I don't know. I need access files and I don't know what the cause of this is. Is it the little battery? I did not try to reset BIOs. I do not have another graphics card to try, it has the second one I have already put in when the power supply was changed. I do not have electrical contact cleaner but the RAM was taken out and put back in before when the blank screen was displayed the first time, and dusted, I do not know if that helped. I do not see anything wrong with the motherboard capacitors either. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 2**

I got a USB with ubuntu on it and plugged it in. It went to the same F1 F2 screen, I pressed F1 to change the boot order and saved and rebooted, seemed to boot to the drive instead of the USB and gave me a purple screen still.
Tried again, it reset the boot order and I changed it again, gave me a purple screen.

Got a disc with ubuntu on it, Changed boot order, saved and reset, and it finally  booted from the disc the second try.
It did a filesystem check and said no errors found and proceeded to go to the same purple screen again.
I can't even try anything past the BIOS menu because it just gives me the purple screen.
I tried before the USB to boot normally and it actually froze on the F1 or F2 screen and didn't register the keyboard, I had to reboot it.
Please help I'm lost.

Comment: So the monitor never shows anything, not even the BIOS/UEFI initial screen? If so it's very likely the graphics or the motherboard are faulty. You can try 1. reset the BIOS/UEFI and/or try another graphics card.

Comment: Two things to do/check for. First, reseat the RAM modules. Spray some electrical contact cleaner on them and the slots and insert and remove them a few times to clean oxidation. Second, look for [leaking or bulged capacitors](https://www.google.com/search?q=leaking+bulged+capacitors+motherboard&tbm=isch) on the motherboard.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The monitor started to show a screen, I wrote more on a edit on the question, it says all settings reset to default press F1 for setup or F2 to continue , I can't boot from USB, disc, or drive. It goes to a purple screen I can move the mouse on but nothing happens ,from disc or drive. It did not boot from the USB but did a filesystem check from disc.I don't have any other graphics cards to try,the previous one was damaged so I thought that was the problem and changed it first. I didn't try to reset BIOS yet,should I?Is there anything else I should try first?

Comment: @Appleoddity The RAM was reseated when the problem started, I don't have electrical contact cleaner and I did not see any damage to the motherboard. I tried to add more information to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it looks like the file system is corrupt, or the HDD has gone bad. To verify the cause of the issue, and possibly fix it,

- Create a live Linux flash USB that contains a drive management utility, e.g. [for Ubuntu OS](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/).
- Boot from the USB, and select *trying* the OS, rather than *installing it* to the drive.
- If you can boot from the USB drive, and it runs well, without crashes, then you've ascertained the issue is with the HDD and/or its file system.

To fix a soft file system error,

- Boot as above, running from the USB. Do *not* mount the HDD in the PC.
- Assuming you use Ubuntu, press <kbd>System</kbd> key, type *disk* and select  the *Disks* utility.
- In [Disks](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/manage-ubuntu-hdd-disk-utility/), click on each partition and select the gear button.
- Try to *Repair* each partition. *N.B.* If repair *fails*, it is worth trying  second time -- I've frequently found it succeeds on the second run!
- You can also use use the tool [fsck](https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/) from terminal to repair the disk.

If, after trying to repair the OS, the disk still has bad partitions, then the best thing to do is to replace the HDD, restoring your last disk image to the new disk. I you do not have a recent image, you can *try* salvaging the data on the disk using that boot USB device.

Comment: *it looks like the file system is corrupt, or the HDD has gone bad* No, not necessarily. The OP has been forcefully shutting down due to freezes that point to other issues. Whenever that happens this is what we see in the next boot and is the result of error correction taking place and the last line says clean, that should be enough to have it again up and running provided there are no other problems. Of course, testing the drives should be done just in case but I suspect not the correct focus here. It certainly is something else if it shows nothing, hence my request to clarification.