# Computer runs but does not boot to desktop, stuck on a purple screen

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, desktop, desktop-computer

It is a older computer, and nothing has ever been changed except hard drives until this started.

The computer started randomly shutting down sometimes or 'suspend', the power button light would blink like it's suspended but you would have to push it and it would go off and then push again to turn back on. It would not respond to anything else except the power button in that state. Assumed it was overheating from the summer heat and dust build-up, it was cleaned but continued to shut itself off.

the computer would turn on, fans run, lights, and sounds like it wants to boot but just a black screen. The monitor did not respond and it has worked fine with this computer for a long time. The graphics card and power supply have been changed to a new power supply and an older unused graphics card. It booted normal about three times only after changing the graphics card, with a longer boot time than usual.
then it started coming up with a screen that said:

```
AMD FX (tm) 4300 quad core processor     , speed: 200x19=3800 M( the picture i took cuts off here so I can't see the rest of this line)

DRAM Frequency for DDR3 1333 MHz( Unganged mode, 64-bit) DRAM Size is 8192 MB

USB Devices total: 0 KBS ,0 MICE, 0 MASS , 0 HUBS

Detected ATA/ATAPI Devices SATA Port3: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM 6H24NSCO SATA Port5: WDC WD10EZEX-00MFCAO

All settings were reset to default values. press F1 to run setup  press F2 to continue,
```

plugged the keyboard in and hit F2 and it worked for awhile. It would boot like this fine and I didn't know what was wrong but everything was working and I didn't have alot of time to sit down and look at it so I left it to boot by unplugging the keyboard, turn it on, plug it in and hit F2.

If I left the keyboard in it didn't seem like it would work and go to a black screen instead but maybe something else was happening there and just happened to boot ok when I unplugged it. Now it has not booted at all the last five times, it would stay on the blank black screen, like the monitor doesn't even turn on, the fans spin, computer lights up, makes sound and then nothing. I tried it again and it went to the screen that says F1 setup or F2 continue, I hit F1 this time to see if something has changed and I didn't see anything wrong so I clicked discard changes(none) and exited the BIOs screen. It rebooted to the F1 or F2 screen so I pressed F2 to continue and it started to boot a little slower then normal, went to a purple screen with the mouse cursor on it, I can move the mouse but it does not give me the desktop.

It is currently ubuntu 20.04 and has been for awhile, it usually flashes this purple with the cursor before the desktop appears when it boots but only for a second, It's stuck on purple it seems.

I got a USB with ubuntu on it and plugged it in. It went to the same F1 F2 screen, I pressed F1 to change the boot order and saved and rebooted, seemed to boot to the drive instead of the USB and gave me a purple screen still. Tried again, it reset the boot order and I changed it again, gave me a purple screen.

Got a disc with ubuntu on it, Changed boot order, saved and reset, and it finally booted from the disc the second try and gave me GRUB.I didn't have time to press anything and it selected ubuntu. It did a filesystem check from the disc and said no errors found and proceeded to go to the same purple screen again. I tried before the USB to boot normally and it froze on the F1 or F2 screen and didn't register the keyboard, I had to reboot it and tried the USB, then the disc.It's just purple with the mouse, all I can do is make the mouse go off screen at the bottom of the screen. Tried changing the monitor settings but no effect.

I really don’t want to lose anything on the hard drive.

Comment: Sounds like the CMOs battery needs to be replaced

Comment: Did anything changed since last year? [Computer runs,but won't display anything on screen, changed power supply and graphics card](https://superuser.com/questions/1748040/computer-runs-but-wont-display-anything-on-screen-changed-power-supply-and-gra)

Comment: If it won't boot from USB, a few possibilities: 1. USB is non bootable. Remake on a new FAT32 USB according to online directions. 2. You might need to hold another key when powering on, e.g. F9 or F12, to select boot device - does USB show in list? 3. BIOS settings may need to be changed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I didn't test the USB before hand but it did say it was a hard drive USB and showed up in the boot options in BIOS. It reset the boot order options when I saved and reboot from BIOS, it seemed like it reboot to the hard drive instead but I am not sure because I only get a ubuntu loading screen and then a purple screen. When I go to BIOS the boot order is back to the previous order even though I saved the changes to boot from USB. It seemed like it boot from a disc after changing the boot order again, it gave me GRUB and ran a filesystem check but did not give me a desktop.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, as I mentioned in the edits to that question and this one, it doesn't let me see a desktop and loads a purple screen after the ubuntu loading screen that only has a mouse cursor on it.
It seems to reset the boot order to its original order when it reboots after I change it. it did seem to boot from a disc and ran a filesystem check but still gave me the purple screen.

Comment: @Ramhound I was considering trying that, Is there anything I should be worried about for that? I don't want to lose hard drive data

Comment: Ah: "When I go to BIOS the boot order is back to the previous order." Could be a bad CMOS battery. Usually they last 5-10 years. Does the BIOS system clock keep time if unplugged? If not, that would confirm the battery (cell, really).

Comment: @Pufferfish - What possible connection to a CMOS battery is there to your HDD/SSD?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  I did not try unplugging it , I think I will try changing the battery though, the computer is about 10 years old though and it does not sound like the battery has ever been changed.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know? I'm not a computer person, that's why I asked the questions in the first place, computer hardware isn't something on my mind regularly and I just don't want to lose the stuff on the HDD.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I changed the battery with a new one and got nothing.  The screen didn't even turn on but everything powers up. I pressed the reset button on the pc case and nothing happened so I held the power button till it turned off. I'm not sure what to do now

Comment: IMO the only real help we can give at this point is to suggest you to have it checked by a competent engineer.